# Dynamic Wizard in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

here don't need any technical help perhaps i need logical steps . i am having project like a questionnaire and its like a wizard . in each wizard step we have several dynamic rules in the sense options in the wizard can be customizable by the end user . in what structure i can keep the rules in database . depend on answers in each step we could decide the options for another step . i am confused , please advice if you have any idea.

Comment: (It should be possible to discuss this without some dummy code.) I'm not sure if you have the appropriate audience here. Consider posting this in programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have something that look like a decision tree.

I'de say it would need two tables : Step and StepOption.

In Step , you specify everything that is common to each step and in StepOption, which is linked to Step, I would put all possible option you ask. Each option would have a link to the step that comes after when you choose the option.

It's a rather simple way to do this and may not be complete enough for you, but I'de say it may be a good start

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer , this thing i know , each step is interrelated with some rule . i am so confused for keeping that rule .