# WPF: Piping in wizard questionnare

Tags: wpf, dynamic, survey

I am a WPF newbie, so don't be to harsh on me if the question is too simple. :)

I would like to create a WPF wizard that would contain a questionnare. The questionnare could possibly be dynamic, i.e. if the end user choose answer b in question 5, it would change question 6 and 7, because they will be related to question 5.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Can I store questions in a XML file? I found that Wizard control is already done in WPF Extended Toolkit (https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard), but I am not sure, how to store data and how to create the conditions for the dynamic questionnare in a simple and straightforward way.

I found this question is quite similar, but not exactly what I need. 
[Dynamic Wizard in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516487/dynamic-wizard-in-wpf)

Thank you!

Comment: This is an extremely open question and you will get opinion based answers. As a new guy, use XML to store your data (its easiest is .net) but _try something_ and see where the issues are. Prototyping and analyzing failures is an excellent tool for learning.

Comment: What @Gusdor said. What have you tried so far? You have only provided us with a vague spec of the app and asked what to do.